# Node.appendChild Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, dom-manipulation

When I retrieve items from my list using REST API, I generate rows to an html table but when I try to append it to a table, I get the following errors:

***Uncaught TypeError: Node.appendChild: Argument 1 is not an object.***

```
function onQuerySucceeded(data) {

    if(data.d && data.d.results){
        var items = data.d.results
        var listItems = ''
        for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
            listItems += '<tr>'
            listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'
            listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'
            listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'
            listItems += '<td>' + items[x].ID + '</td>'
            listItems += '</tr>'
        }
    }
    

    document.getElementById("service").appendChild(listItems)   //<---- Error
}
```

I know it's because **listItems** is not an object but I'm not sure how get it to where it needs to be.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not related to SharePoint, however, you can use HTML DOM innerHTML Property if you want to show constructed HTML inside a DIV.

```
document.getElementById("service").innerHTML = listItems;
```

Details on innerHTML: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try to use jQuery:

```
$("#service").append(listItems)
```